# SQL SUM without a GROUP BY

Tags: sql-server

I've written a SQL SELECT to sum up the contents of a temp table. An MCVE is:

```
WITH cte
AS
(
  SELECT Change FROM (VALUES('INSERT'), ('INSERT'), ('INSERT'), ('INSERT'), ('UPDATE'), ('UPDATE'), ('UPDATE'), ('DELETE'), ('DELETE')) AS A(CHANGE)
)
SELECT  ' I=' + CAST(SUM(IIF(Change = 'INSERT', 1, 0)) AS VARCHAR(10)) +
        ' U=' + CAST(SUM(IIF(Change = 'UPDATE', 1, 0)) AS VARCHAR(10)) +
        ' D=' + CAST(SUM(IIF(Change = 'DELETE', 1, 0)) AS VARCHAR(10))
FROM    cte;
```

(In the original code the table I'm reading from has more columns than just Change (it is actually the OUTPUT from a MERGE statement and I'm logging what the MERGE did) but I only refer to the one column in the SELECT, as above.)

This works and gives me what I expect: `I=4 U=3 D=2`

However I realized in a code review that I omitted the `GROUP BY Change` statement.

So I'm left wondering how the above code works?

Comment: You have no other columns to group by. The aggregated column does not need to be in the group by.

Comment: See the results on this fiddle for no grouping and with grouping: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/48375/2

Comment: When everything in your select list is inside a aggregating functions (such as `sum`, `count` etc'), and you don't specify a `group by`, the aggregation is done on all the rows returned from the query.

Comment: @JacobH thanks. I deleted the comment you are replying to because I tried adding a group by and got 3 lines (as expected). I understand how it works now. I don't think I've ever done this before in 15+ years of writing SQL.

Answer (score 0):

from the Syntax point of view, you only need to use `Group By`, whenever you have one or more column(s) which are not included in the Aggregate Functions(SUM, AVG, COUNT, MIN, MAX).

In your example you are going to select the `Change` column, which is currently included in the `SUM` aggregate function, so you do not need to use the `Group By` .

But if you want to select the `Change` and `X` columns, as only `Change` is included in the aggregate function, you will need to add `Group By X`. which mean that you are going to do an aggregate on `Change` for each group of `X`.

[Lear more about GROUP BY here.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-group-by-transact-sql)